# Can i take a model i created in blender and spin/rotate it in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm creating a model in blender:

[image: Propeller]

I want to rotate/spin the propeller and to control the time and speed of the rotation. And i want to use this model/object in unity3d for a game.

So i wonder if i should make the whole rotation animation part in blender first or to do it in unity3d ? This propeller is part of a bigger model a drone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Option 1:
  Animate it in Blender
- Option 2:
  Make the two pieces two separate meshes / objects so that they can be animated in Unity. They **must** have two separate transforms when imported or this won't work.